# use std:array as an argument of function

Tags: c++

I have seen here :http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/
that 
int[N] is the same as `std::array<int,N>` in C++.
 I would like to use this notation in order to avoid to pass N as an argument of a function.

I would like to do something like that

```
returnedType function(array tab)
```

instead of

```
returnedType function(int tab, int N)
```

but i can't make the type array because i must write `array<int,N>` and i don't know N in advance. 
Has Somebody  a solution?

Comment: use `std::vector`. or `span` in C++20

Comment: @Unholy Please don't recommend to beginners using a standard that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @NeilButterworth would recommending `gsl::span` instead be acceptable?

Comment: @Unholy To me, in this case? No.

Comment: Saying that `int[N]` is the same as `std::array<int, N>` is a bit of a stretch. If that was the case, we wouldn't need `std::array` to begin with.

Comment: @Pierre Thus is an english language website, so please post links to english resources. And what you want is almost certainly a std::vector.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm sorry. Now the link is in English

Comment: @Pierre That is an awful resource. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `function` a *function `template`*, like so:

```
template <size_t N>
void function(std::array<int, N> arr)
{
    // do something with arr
}
```

and call it like:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> a;
    function(a);

    std::array<int, 15> b;
    function(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do not know the size in advance, std::vector is what you want

```
//function taking vector:
int MyFunc(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
 //.. do stuff
 return 5;
}


std::vector<int> myvec;
//add somme entries:
myvec.push_back(1);
myvec.push_back(2);
myvec.push_back(3);
//call function:
int res = MyFunc(myvec);
```